# xml string to class conversion

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have string that represents xml serialized class.
I have xsd of this class and I successfully managed to create a class from it.

Now I am looking for a way how to serialize this string to instance of this class.
What is the best way doing so?

Thanks.

Comment: It's called Deserialize and there is a built-in support for this in .net. Check out XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different serializers in .NET, such as the binary formatter, soap formatter, the XML serializer, etc.  Some of them use XML, some don't.  They have different pro's and cons, but for basic uses, often people just use the `XmlSerializer` which uses XML to represent the object:

```
public T DeSerialize<T>(string serializedObject)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using StringReader reader = new StringReader(serializedObject)
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```